# My for dont find string in file I dont know where I make mistake

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a few files to load I want to divide them into those that have a' content ...' line inside and those that don't have it, but my program put everything to a dictionary whose name is empty.

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilenames() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
print(filename)

content = {}
for file in filename:
    fp = open(file, 'r')
    lines = fp.readlines()
x ='Content'
content = {'is_in':[],'empty':[]}
with open(file) as myfile:
    head = [next(myfile) for x in range(0,4)]
for line in head:
    if x in line:
        whole_line = line
        whole_line = ''.join(whole_line.split())
        result = whole_line.replace('Content','')
        content['is_in'].append(file)
    elif result not in head:
        content['empty'].append(file)
```

Comment: What does that input file contain?

Comment: `elif result not in head` "result" is not defined unless it was found in an earlier loop. It will throw an error if the first line of the header does not contain `x`. Intended?

Comment: your problem is `elif` - first you should check all lines and set variabe `found =True` and after `for`-loop use `if not found: content['empty'].append(file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me all your `elif` makes no sense.

You should first check all lines in `head` and set ie. `found = True` and after `for`-loop use this variable to add to `content['empty']`

```
    searched = 'contente'  # I will compare with `line.lower()`

    # --- before `for`-loop ---

    found = False

    # --- `for`-loop ---

    for line in head:
        if searched in line.lower():  # compare lower case 
            content['is_in'].append(file)
            found = True
            break  # there is no need to search in next lines
    
    # --- after `for`-loop ---

    if not found:
        content['empty'].append(file)
```

Eventually you could use `content['is_in']` for this

```
    searched = 'contente'  # I will compare with `line.lower()`

    # --- `for`-loop ---

    for line in head:
        if searched in line.lower():  # compare lower case 
            content['is_in'].append(file)
            break  # there is no need to search in next lines
    
    # --- after `for`-loop ---

    if file not in content['is_in']:
        content['empty'].append(file)
```

---

Python has also special construction `for/else/break` which runs `else` when  `break` was not used in `for`

```
    searched = 'contente'  # I will compare with `line.lower()`

    # --- `for`-loop ---

    for line in head:
        if searched in line.lower():  # compare lower case 
            content['is_in'].append(file)
            break  # there is no need to search in next lines
    else:  # in the same column as `for` (not as `if`)
        content['empty'].append(file)

    # --- after `for`-loop ---
```

---

Full working example with other changes.

I keep some ideas in comments.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
all_filenames = askopenfilenames() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
print('all_filenames:', all_filenames)
root.destroy()  # remove it from memory

content = {
    'is_in': [],
    'empty': [],
}

searched = 'contente'  # I will compare with `line.lower()`

for filename in all_filenames:
   
    with open(filename) as file:
        head = [next(file) for _ in range(4)]

    # --- befere `for`-loop ---

    found = False

    # --- `for`-loop ---
    
    for line in head:
        #if line.lower().startswith(searched):  # compare lower case 
        if searched in line.lower():  # compare lower case 
            content['is_in'].append(filename)
            found = True
            break # there is no need to search in next lines
    #else:
    #    content['empty'].append(filename)

    # --- after `for`-loop ---
        
    #if not filename in content['is_in']:
    if not found:
        content['empty'].append(filename)
        
# ---

print('is_in:', content['is_in'])
print('empty:', content['empty'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you use the `scope` for `result` variable.
If on the first iteration the `if x in line` returns `False` it will got for `elif result not in head` but at this point `result` is not defined yet.
Also, if at first iteration `if x in line` returns `True`, it will not even check the `elfi` statement. Will go forward to next iteration, and let's suppose that the next will reach `elfi`. Here you still don't have the `result` defined, since `result` was defined in the previous loop inside the `if` statement.

Please read about [python scope](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)